# Nokogiri should not include DOCTYPE

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to produce a partial HTML document using Nokogiri, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
html_content = Nokogiri::HTML::Builder.new() do |doc|
  # producing document here, redacted for brevity
end.to_html
```

This works well enough, except for a little catch: data will later be dispatched to a remote Drupal-powered server and rendered as part of a page and thus should *not* contain the initial `<!DOCTYPE html ...>` declaration.

How would I go about convincing Nokogiri not to produce the `DOCTYPE` tag? Or is Nokogiri's HTML builder the wrong way to go about that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve this you could use [document fragments](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/DocumentFragment.html) and the [`Builder.with`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-c-with) method, like this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
include Nokogiri

fragment = HTML.fragment('')

HTML::Builder.with(fragment) do |f|
  f.div('foo')
end

fragment.to_html
# => <div>foo</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Nokogiri makes it easy to create templates you can populate on the fly; I'd do it this way:

```
require 'nokogiri'

DESTINATION_HOST = 'http://www.example.com/some/API/call'

HTML_TEMPLATE = <<EOT
<form method="post">
  <input name="user" type="text">
  <input name="desc" type="text">
</form>
<div id="quote">
</div>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(HTML_TEMPLATE)

doc.at('form')['action'] = DESTINATION_HOST
doc.at('div').content = "Danger is my middle name."
[
  ['user', 'Austin Powers'],
  ['desc', 'Man of Mystery'],
].each do |name, value|
  doc.at("input[name=\"#{name}\"]")['value'] = value
end

puts doc.to_html
# >> <form method="post" action="http://www.example.com/some/API/call">
# >>   <input name="user" type="text" value="Austin Powers"><input name="desc" type="text" value="Man of Mystery">
# >> </form>
# >> <div id="quote">Danger is my middle name.</div>
```

The array and other fields that are populated could easily be loaded from a CSV or YAML file, JSON retrieved on the fly from another host, or directly from a database call.

You know how your document should look beforehand, so use that knowledge to create a template. Nokogiri's Builder is better suited for those times you're not even sure what tags you're going to need and need to dynamically build the entire document structure on the fly.

The hardest part is to define how you're going to loop over various tags in the document to stuff them with content or fill in the parameters, but once you've done that it's easy to create boilerplate you fill in and forward to something else.